# Custom redirecting when user is trying to access to restricted actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, model-view-controller, authorization

I have an application with the custom form authentication. I have added restrictions on accessing to some actions based on user roles. I have overridden `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)` and it works OK. The only problem is that currently the application redirects a user to a login page if for instance "Editor" is trying to access to actions available only for "Admins". I know it is because I have set the default page to `log-in` page in `Web.config`. Ideally I would like a user to be redirected to a warning page instead of a login page. How can I do it?

Thanks

EDIT:
The answer to this question may also be found here:
[ASP.NET MVC redirect to an access denied page using a custom role provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279643/asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-an-access-denied-page-using-a-custom-role-provider)

Comment: look into filters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977071/redirecting-unauthorized-controller-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498727/asp-net-mvc-how-to-show-unauthorized-error-on-login-page

Comment: I found the perfect solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279643/asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-an-access-denied-page-using-a-custom-role-provider

Thanks guys!