# ASP.NET MVC - How to show unauthorized error on login page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

In my ASP.NET MVC app, I have most controllers decorated with

```
[Authorize(Roles="SomeGroup")]
```

When a user is not authorized to access something, they are sent to "~/Login" which is the Login action on my Account controller.

How can I determine that a user has reached the login page because of not being authorized so that I can show an appropriate error?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can look for the `?ReturnUrl=`  querystring value, or you can create your own authorization filter & set a field in `TempData` indicating the reason.

Here is a simple custom filter that will do the trick:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    // NOTE: This is not thread safe, it is much better to store this
    // value in HttpContext.Items.  See Ben Cull's answer below for an example.
    private bool _isAuthorized;

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        _isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        return _isAuthorized;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if(!_isAuthorized)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.TempData.Add("RedirectReason", "Unauthorized");
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your view, you can do something like this:

```
@if(TempData["RedirectReason"] == "Unauthorized")
{
    <b>You don't have permission to access that area</b>
}
```

*(Though I'd recommend a better approach than these magic strings, but you get the point)*

Comment: Thanks Ben, I implement the same on my side and work very well!

Comment: This answer is accepted, but it is not thread safe, please see answer below for more details. Please update your code to be thread safe, a lot of developers may not read other answers and use yours as the best.

Comment: Added a comment to this effect.

Comment: I noticed this comment when copied that code to my project and started to read-refactor it there :)

Answer (score 81):

**UPDATE (Jun 2015):** @daniel-lidström has correctly pointed out that you should not use Response.Redirect in an ASP.NET MVC application. For more information about why, please see this link: [Response.Redirect and ASP.NET MVC – Do Not Mix](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/01/response-redirect-and-asp-net-mvc-do-not-mix.aspx).

**UPDATE (Sep 2014):** I'm not sure when HandleUnauthorizedRequest was added to the AuthorizeAttribute, but either way I've been able to refine the AuthorizeRedirect code into something smaller and simpler.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AuthorizeRedirect : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string RedirectUrl = "~/Error/Unauthorized";

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(RedirectUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Original Answer Below (still fully functional)**

I've left this answer here as it still gives you an insight as to how the Authorization pipeline works.

For anyone still landing here, I've edited Ben Scheirman's answer to automatically redirect to an unauthorized page when the user is logged in but not authorized. You can change the redirect path using the name parameter RedirectUrl.

**EDIT:** I've made the solution thread-safe thanks to the advice of [Tarynn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751049/tarynn) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AuthorizeRedirect : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private const string IS_AUTHORIZED = "isAuthorized";

    public string RedirectUrl = "~/error/unauthorized";

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        httpContext.Items.Add(IS_AUTHORIZED, isAuthorized);

        return isAuthorized;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        var isAuthorized = filterContext.HttpContext.Items[IS_AUTHORIZED] != null 
            ? Convert.ToBoolean(filterContext.HttpContext.Items[IS_AUTHORIZED]) 
            : false;

        if (!isAuthorized && filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(RedirectUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From MSDN:

Deriving from AuthorizeAttribute


If you derive from the AuthorizeAttribute class, the derived type must be thread safe. Therefore, do not store state in an instance of the type itself (for example, in an instance field) unless that state is meant to apply to all requests. Instead, store state per request in the Items property, which is accessible through the context objects passed to AuthorizeAttribute.

isn't the _isAuthorized an instance field?

Comment: Does this method work with FormsAuth and the default redirect?

Comment: Yep, the default non-authenticated redirect will be unaffected.

Comment: You can simplify the inline if statement to: `filterContext.HttpContext.Items[IsAuthorized] != null && Convert.ToBoolean(filterContext.HttpContext.Items[IsAuthorized]);` Note: cahnged `ISAUTHORIZED` to `IsAuthorized`

Comment: Would not work with multiple controller actions rendered on one page. `Additional information: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'isAuthorized'  Key being added: 'isAuthorized'`

Comment: Hmm good point, although if you're calling child actions, marking them with `ChildActionOnly` and putting the `AuthoriseRedirect` on the parent action should work.

Comment: I would say that this answer should be accepted as best answer to this question.

Comment: it work perfect but i want to mention some note here. it take me more than 2 hours because some mistake when implement. 
- Don't add to filter like filters.Add(new AuthorizeRedirect());
- In controller implement it like:
   [AuthorizeRedirect(Roles = "Admins")]
    public class RoleController : Controller
.Not implement like
[Authorize(Roles = "Admins")]
    public class RoleController : Controller

Comment: Instead of having the redirect dependency in the class, I replaced it with `filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.AddError(new HttpException(403, "You have no power here..."));` Which lets me use `customError` from the web.config. I still wish there was a way to actually return a `403` instead of the `302` though.

Comment: If I implement both HandleUnauthorizedRequest and OnAuthorization, why does HandleUnauthorizedRequest never be run?

Comment: @Dabbas Nope definitely just if(). It's saying if you're authenticaed (logged in) but not authorized (have permission) then redirect to a page that says "I know you're logged in and not allowed to be here".

Comment: filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(RedirectUrl) - For me this actually does perform the redirect yet also throws a "System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent." under the hood. Can this be avoided and if so how?

Comment: Potentially you could call the base method *after* the redirect to see if that helps?

Comment: @ProNotion @BenCull This code is incorrect. You should use the `filterContext.Result` as shown by @divide_byzero's answer. `Response.Redirect` is not supported by MVC, as you can tell from the `System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005)`.

Comment: @daniel-lidström You're absolutely right, well done! I've updated the code with the correct implementation.

Comment: Note that the AuthorizeAttribute listed here is in the *System.Web.Mvc* namespace.   When I tried this solution, I accidentally used the System.Web.Http namespace.   See my answer below for more details.

Comment: @Willy if you want HandleUnauthorizedRequest to be ran from OnAuthorization, you should add this piece of code: filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();

Answer (score 6):

Ben Cull's method works well, but remember there are two AuthorizeAttribute classes - one in System.Web.HTTP (used by Web API), and the other in System.Web.Mvc.   Ben's method uses the System.Web.Mvc class.  For clarity, I suggest using the fully qualified path.

If you're using Web API alongside MVC, you will need to implement two filters:

```
public class AuthorizeRedirectMVCAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/AccessDenied");
        }
    }
}

public class AuthorizeRedirectAPIAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);

        if (actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that asp.net will let you decorate your MVC controller with an API filter - it just won't work the way you expect, so keep your attribute names explicit.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a controller and don't want to have a url in you code you can redirect this way as well.  It will not change the url in the address bar of the browser so the user will never see the url for the unauthorized page.  This was written in MVC 3.  This method will also work if you want to redirect them to a login page or if you want to redirect them to a page to just tell them they aren't authorized.  I had section in the program that some user didn't have rights to but they were logged in so this is what I used.

```
public class AuthorizedRedirect : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        return isAuthorized;
    }
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "error";
    filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "unauthorized" };
}
```

Comment: As another variation to show the message in a Shared View, e.g.       `var vr = new ViewResult();    vr.ViewName = "Info";               vr.ViewBag.Message = "You are unauthorized for this page; contact us. ";       filterContext.Result = vr;`

Answer (score 2):

And an even simpler version that utilizes FormsAuthentication settings. For those not familiar with Contract, Contract.Requires is a .NET 4 addition. Pros and cons to using [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts).

```
public class RequiresAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        Contract.Requires(filterContext != null);

        HttpContextBase context = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;

        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // user does not possess the required role permission
            string url = context.GetCustomErrorUrl(401);
            context.Response.Redirect(url);
        }
        else
        {

            // redirect the user to the login page
            string extraQueryString  = context.Request.RawUrl;
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage(extraQueryString);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Going further from divide_byzero's answer even if you don't have a controller you can still use the HandleUnauthorizedRequest to change the redirect.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class AuthoriseRedirect : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("UrlToRedirectTo");
        }
    }
```

Comes in handy if you have a legacy webforms site that you will be converting to MVC over a longer period of time.....!

Answer (score 0):

I like what Brian Vander Plaats posted, just added few improvements:

```
/// <summary>
/// Authorize or redirect to an unauthorized MVC action if the user does not have the required roles
/// (an unauthenticated user will be redirected to the defualt sign in action)
/// <para>Decorate an action or a controller like this [AuthorizeAndRedirect(Roles = "RoleName")]</para>
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AuthorizeOrRedirectAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Unauthorized");
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeData.Values);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Authorize or redirect to an unauthorized API action if the user does not have the required roles
/// (an unauthenticated user will be redirected to the defualt sign in action)
/// <para>Decorate an action or a controller like this [AuthorizeAndRedirect(Roles = "RoleName")]</para>
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AuthorizeOrRedirectApiFilterAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);

        if (actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}
```