# Redirect from AuthorizeCore to another controller with custom error message

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext

So I trying to show user a message, when he got redirected from page where he is not authorized to see. Example: User go to www.mypage.com/users and get redirected to www.mypage.com/home.

I using MVC pattern and it is asp.net web application.
I override AuthorizeAttribute and in AuthorizeCore method trying this:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {


            if (false)//Here is custom logic that is working
            {
                string message = "You don't have an access to selected menu item.";
                var dataDict = HttpContext.Current.Session["__ControllerTempData"] as IDictionary<string, object>;
                if (dataDict == null)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    dictionary["myErrorMessage"] = message;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["__ControllerTempData"] = dictionary;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataDict["myErrorMessage"] = message;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["__ControllerTempData"] = dataDict;
                }

                _isAuthorized = false;

                httpContext.Response.Redirect("Home");                
            }
            else
            {
                _isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            }

            return _isAuthorized;
        }
```

And then I trying to access it from the view as

```
var unauthorized_access_message = TempData["myErrorMessage"] as List <string> ?? new List<string>() ;
```

But it does not work. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498727/asp-net-mvc-how-to-show-unauthorized-error-on-login-page), but it not the case as I trying to access one controller and then redirect to another one.
Is there any solution to pass variable to the view or check some status(like redirection reason) in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using Cookies.

Setting cookie in CustomAuthorizeAttribute:AuthorizeAttribute class:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
            {

                if (false)
                {
                    HttpCookie mycookie= new HttpCookie("unauthorize_error", "You do not have access to requested link.");
                    httpContext.Response.SetCookie(mycookie);
                    httpContext.Response.Redirect("Home");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
                }
            }
```

Then in controller:

```
string cookieValue = string.Empty;
            if (Request.Cookies["myCookieName"] != null
                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Cookies["myCookieName"].Value))
            {
                cookieValue = Request.Cookies["myCookieName"].Value;
                var myCookie = new System.Web.HttpCookie("myCookieName");
                myCookie.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
                Response.Cookies.Add("myCookieName");
            }
var messages = TempData["mytemperror"] as List<string> ?? new List<string>();
            messages.Add(message);
            TempData["myTempError"] = messages;
```

And finally in view:

```
var errorMessage = TempData["myTempError"] as List<string> ?? new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `AuthorizeCore`, could you override `OnAuthorization`  in which you can access `TempData` directly from `Controller`?

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (false)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.TempData["myErrorMessage"] =
            "You don't have an access to selected menu item.";
    }
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```

**Usage**

```
string unauthorized_access_message = (TempData["myErrorMessage"] ?? "").ToString();
```

Comment: Sorry, but that does not work. I think it is because of redirection. Lets say someone tries to access Account controller, but does not have permission to it(it will hit the OnAuthorization and set tempdata), so he will be redirected to Home controller (and it will hit again OnAuthorization but after that there is no that TempData anymore). At least when I trying to access it from Home/Index it is empty string.

Comment: Normally, anonymous user should be redirected to `Login page` instead of `Home page`, unless home page all owes anonymous access.

Comment: The thing is that it is not anonymous user. I have custom authentication. So user is authenticated but not authorized, lets say Admin can access Account/Members, where he can get list of members. But if Member will try to access it he must go to Home/Index and see notification "No permission".

Comment: How about straight access to session state? After retrieving the message, you insert `null` value there. `var unauthorized_access_message = Session["ErrorMessage"] as List <string> ?? new List<string>(); Session["ErrorMessage"] = null;`

Comment: For some reason Session doesn't worked as well. Tried it. But I found solution and will post it as answer.