# Custom Redirection if Roles don't match

Tags: asp.net-mvc, role

I have an Action result

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,Paidmember")]
public ActionResult ListPhotosbyModel(int? id)
{

}
```

If the user once he is logged in is not in one of the roles he redirected to login screen but I want them redirected to a payment page where upon successful completion the user is added to `paidmember`.

How do I redirect to a payment page not the login page if not in one of those roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write a custom authorization attribute like [tvanfosson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12950/tvanfosson) does in his answer 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977071/redirecting-unauthorized-controller-in-asp-net-mvc).

You will then be able to do something like

```
[MyAuthorize(Roles = "Administrator,Paidmember", ViewName = "paidmember")]
```

This is working great for me.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is override the Authorize attribute, and return your own ActionResult, when the Role is the wrong one.

Comment: Any info on how to do this exactly?