# reject user to specific view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

i have mvc2 project and i make custom role Provider I'm using attributes [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] to prevent an authorized user from doing some actions
that always reject user to log in view i want to change that and redirect user to view that I'm tilling him that he isn't authorized for this action

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult delete(int id)
    {
       ...........
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirecting unauthorized controller in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977071/redirecting-unauthorized-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recurring question:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265047/custom-redirection-if-roles-dont-match) & [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977071/redirecting-unauthorized-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)