# MVC4: When to redirect failed login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I am using MVC4 with **Windows Authentication** for an Intranet site.

My **Controllers** are based on my **BaseController**

**BaseController** will call out to a service to see if the Windows user is allowed to use the site. If not, I want to redirect them to "Index" on the Controller "UnAuthorized"

Where in the **BaseController** would I check and then how would I redirect the request to the UnAuthorized controller?

I have tried to redirect in the **OnAuthorized** like this but nothing happens:

```
    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (!isAuthorized(username))
            RedirectToAction("Index", "UnAuthorized");
    }
```

Comment: Are you manually calling out to this service to see if the user is authorized? If so then you redirect when you get the response back.

Comment: Where do I redirect though?

Comment: You redirect back to your login page and notify the user that their username/password was incorrect. If they tried to access a page without being logged in then you redirect to the login page and notify the user that they must login to access the other page.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, in the BaseController I check for Authentication, then in the BaseController, in what method do I call RedirectToAction?

Comment: I don't know, your solution seems non-standard to the built in membership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will probably help you

[Redirect Unauthorised Controller in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977071/redirecting-unauthorized-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Also This video will give you some general help

[windows authentication in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4hzVLZjfLM)