# allow unauthorized request for specific actionmethods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I registered a MessageHandler (with config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ValidationHandler()) which inherits from DelegatingHandler. It checks each Request for a security token and checks if it is valid.

I got 2 or 3 actionmethods in my Controller which should be accessabel without any authorization.

My Problem:
The MessageHandler is called first. So the actionmethod which should be accessabel from everywhere will be handled as a unauthorized request.
I'm not abel to change the code of the MessageHandler.
I tried to add the allowanonymous attribute, but i still get an unauthorized response.

I found this post [Redirecting unauthorized controller in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977071/redirecting-unauthorized-controller-in-asp-net-mvc) . So my current idea would be to forward the user on the HandleUnauthorizedRequest to the proper action method. But I think it's not the best way.

Is there a better way for this? Is there a way to tell the web.config that actionmethod1 and actionmethod2 are allowed to be accessed as Unauthorizeded user?

[Edit]
Creating an UnAuthorizeAttribute with the AuthorizeAttribute which forwards the user still to the action methods doesn't work. The messagehandler "kills" the request with

```
            statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => new HttpResponseMessage(statusCode));
```

So the  UnAuthorizeAttribute will not be invoked. I'm using asp.net mvc webapi

Comment: [AllowAnonymous] attribute is not suitable?

Comment: AllowAnonymous will not work, because the actionmethod with the AllowAnonymous attribute will not be called when Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)); is set

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating actionfilter to handle this as you know the request you are getting into the controller / action. This is just and idea.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/650240/A-Simple-Action-Filter-Overview

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using a BaseController (WebAPI) and overrided the method  ExecuteAsync(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) and added an breakpoint. But it will not be hit if an unauthorized request was made.