# asp.net mvc Not authorized response is blank page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

If i'm not authorized on a controller action, i am getting a blank page and no error message? I'd like to display a message of some sort, Here's my setup:

```
class MyAuth : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        return MyIsCurrentUserInRoles(Roles.Split(",".ToCharArray()));
    }
}
```

used as

```
[Myauth(Roles="admin")]
class MyController: Controller
{
}
```

and the result is  blank page when i'm not authorized ?

Is that the default behaviour ? if so, what where do i change it to produce a unauth message ?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is the default behaviour when running in the ASP.Net Development Server:

[ASP.Net MVC Authorisation action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491271/asp-net-mvc-authorisation-action-filter-question)

You can redirect it to a page by editing the web.config to include a redirect for error 401:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx" mode="On"> 
    <error statusCode="401" redirect="AccessDenied.aspx" />       
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 2):

You  can override HandleUnauthorized like AuthorizeCore to say redirect to NoAccess page.

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                   new RouteValueDictionary {
                               { "controller", "NoAuthPages" },    
                               { "action", "NoAccess" }                                       
                               });
    }
```