# asp.net MVC: RescueAttribute (mvccontrib) vs HandleErrrorsAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

I recently came across the rescue attribute which is part of the mvccontrib project... At first glance it appeared to allow you to server up different error views depending on controller / actions etc..

But taking a closer look, it also appears that the standard HandleError attribute that ships with mvc also allows you to do the same..

So i am a little confused, what are the pros and cons using the Rescue attribute... it seems to do exactly the same as the HandleError

Any help or insight really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the differences but one of them is that the `HandleError` attribute only works with the `<customError>` section of your web.config which has to be set to `<customError mode="On" />` while `RescueAttribute` works without this section.

see also the answer from Corin in this question for an other difference:
[ASP.NET MVC HandleError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183316/asp-net-mvc-handleerror)