# redirect from Application_Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

How can I redirect  to another page from  `Application_Error`?

At present i am doing

```
Response.Redirect("~/Account/LogOn");
```

but i would like to do some thing like `RedirectToAction()`

Answer (score 5):

Application_Error is not really a designed way to handle errors in MVC application.

The prefered ways are:

- [HandleErrorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.aspx)
- [Controller.OnException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onexception.aspx)

Some more links that can be helpful:

- [ASP.NET MVC HandleError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183316/asp-net-mvc-handleerror)
- http://www.davidjuth.com/asp-net-mvc-error-handler.aspx
- http://blog.dantup.com/2009/04/aspnet-mvc-handleerror-attribute-custom.html

Also, I would recommend using [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) if you're not using it right now. You can get it as NuGet package.

Answer (score 4):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectToRoute(...)
```

Comment: The context is not available before the application startup is completed.  In most cases of handling global errors, this will throw an exception at runtime.  Not sure why this has been voted up so much, it's not a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Action("ServerError", "Error");

Response.Redirect(urlHelper, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to mention one shouldn't be redirecting on errors -- you don't want to send HTTP 3xx headers there and you can have nasty redirect loops when things are really going down across the board.

Comment: There are lots of good reasons to redirect on an "error".  For example, IIS treats 404s as errors, and there are many cases where you want a permanent or other redirect instead of responding with the 404, etc.