# error handling in asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created an MVC3 application and added cutomerrors attribute  **on** in web.config. It works in chrome and Firefox but When I run it in IE9, I get

The website cannot display the page

HTTP 500

Most likely causes:
•The website is under maintenance.
•The website has a programming error.

What you can try:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known problem in Internet Explorer versions where a custom error page has to be at least 512 bytes. While this usually applies to old IE versions and usually resulting in a 404 error page, I'd recommend to ensure that your custom error page is, say 1 kB of size. You might put some HTML comments in or something. Just to ensure that it has nothing to do with that old IE bug.

Just one reference of many:
http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/01/21/important-note-for-your-custom-error-pages/

Comment: thanks it worked. One issue however is that as I am using VS developement server. so when I run my MVC application, It hits the place where exception has occurred in controller and then I press enter to show error page. can't It go directly to error page ?

Comment: what do you mean with "it hits the place"? Do you mean VS holds in debugger? If so, you might use your Visual Studio Main Menu "Debug" » "Exceptions..." and there you can setup which exceptions you want to handle, this might help. For more control, you might look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183316/asp-net-mvc-handleerror/192371#192371 (But this is another story)

Comment: Thanks! After countless hours of trying to figure it out... Gotta love IE. +1

Answer (score 0):

That's the inbuilt IE error page. Can you post your web.config so we can see what you have in there?

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Home/Error">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Home/NoAccess" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Home/NotFound" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Home/Internal" />
</customErrors>
```

Is what I'd expect to see in the web config. I'm not sure what page is being shown in the other browsers.

I guess IE9 is expecting some content to be returned, try adding the Internal action and view to your home controller and specifying defaultRedirect="/Home/Internal" and see if that works.