# How can I make an error page appear in my MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Currently I am getting error pages like this:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The partial view 'obj' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
```

Is there a way that I can just return a plain error page to my users when my code has a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an error page in your web.config

http://www.aspdev.org/articles/web.config/

Answer (score 1):

You should add [HandleError] attribute on top of your controller class. In your web.config add or change <customErrors> to <customErrors mode="on" />.

Also, here is a great article about different filters in MVC. One of the attributes covered is HandleError and it shows how to show your users plain text error messages.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gduthie/archive/2011/03/17/get-to-know-action-filters-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-handleerror.aspx

Regards,

Huske

Answer (score 0):

Following links will give you valuable insight on using custom error pages in asp.net mvc
[ASP.NET MVC HandleError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183316/asp-net-mvc-handleerror)
[ASP.NET MVC 404 Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use OnError method in global.asax

**2.You can use ErrorHandler attribute and put it on controller or action.**

**3.You can use GlobalFilters to add error handling to all controllers. This is recommended way and alternative to global.asax**

4.You can configure error handling in web.config.