# SQL Exception breaks IIS request pipeline

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, request-pipeline

I have MVC3 app that is making IIS go crazy. And me too.

If SQLException happens (ie stored procedure is missing) request pipeline breaks, user sees "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request", nothing is logged in event viewer. Request tracing gives absolutely no useful info but you can take a look [here](http://pastebin.com/CHe51efm). Interesting part is on line 6448 where error code is "The operation completed successfully".

Now here is the fun part:

- my machine win7 64bit - works as expected, YSOD is shown
- one of my hosting machines win2008 web server 32bit - works as expected, YSOD is shown
- client's hosting machine win2008 R2 server core 64 bit - pipeline breaks as described above
- (for testing purposes) client's hosting machine win2008 web server 64 bit - pipeline breaks as described above

UPDATE: this problem is not limited to SQLException. ANY Exception ie throw new Exception("Bla") will break pipeline as described above.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by *broken pipeline*.

Comment: In this situation broken pipeline means sqlexception was not handled by IIS/ASP.NET as it usually would be handled

Comment: Is the application pool you have hosted your application into running in Integrated mode? Or Classic mode?

Comment: Yes, pool is running in Integrated mode.

Comment: Is the rest of the application working (if no exceptions are thrown)?

Comment: Yes, if no exceptions are thrown everything is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is because you probably have the attribute `[HandleError]` somewhere in your controllers.This attribute always catches uncaught exceptions and displays the default Error.cshtm view which can be found in your shared folder.

For more info see this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183316/asp-net-mvc-handleerror).

Regards.

Comment: None of my controllers have HandleError attribute.

Comment: But I did have global filter HandleErrorAttribute. I missed it in global.asax. Only question that remains is why do some IIS/ASP.NET configurations ignore this? Thank you for your help.