# How to return View with IController Execute() that contains Resource values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, resources

I`m doing custom error handling. 
My code:
Global.asax:

```
 public void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        Server.ClearError();

        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "ErrorPage");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error");
        routeData.Values.Add("exception", new HandleErrorInfo(exception, "ErrorPage", "Error"));

        if (exception.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", ((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode());
        }
        else
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", 500);
        }

        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        var controller = new ErrorPageController();

        ((IController)controller).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
        Response.End();
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class ErrorPageController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Error(int statusCode, HandleErrorInfo exception)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        ViewBag.StatusCode = statusCode.ToString();
        return View(exception);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Resource.Error+ " " + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.StatusCode)) ? ViewBag.StatusCode : "500" ;
}

<h1 class="error">@(Resource.Error + " " + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.StatusCode)) ? ViewBag.StatusCode : "500" +". "+ Resource.Sorry):</h1>
<h4><a href ="@Url.Action("Index","Home")"><i>@Resource.MainPage</i></a></h4>
```

This is basically slightly changed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29712033/6850351) answer.
If my view contains any `Resource` values, browser only gets error code, without page. If I remove all of them, works just fine. Any ideas how make view work with resouces?
Also, should `controller` from `Application_Error` be disposed in the method?

Comment: Sometimes resource doesn't appear if file is not completely full. For example if your resource.rsx file has 20 entries then resource.lang.resx must have the same 20 entries. It doesn't matter that you don't use it at the time

Comment: @DaniilT. got it. Maybe will try to fully fill files later. In this case, is it possible that resource values don't work only for one view?

Comment: I put my answer. Probably... I'm not quite sure. But I have kind of situation that localization didn't appear when resource not full in all resource files.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes resource doesn't appear if file is not completely full. For example if your resource file has 20 entries then resource.lang.resx must have the same 20 entries. It doesn't matter that you don't use it at the time