# Throw message after successfully insert into database or error message if not successful

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am inserting into my database. My code is working fine, but am stuck trying to throw message if the insertion is successful or not. Please check my code below. For example, if the insertion is successful, a message like "Insertion successful" should be shown.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SalesLayanEntities3 db = new SalesLayanEntities3();
        List<Product_Category> list = db.Product_Category.ToList();
        ViewBag.ProductName = new SelectList(list,"cat_id","cat_name");

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SaveRecord(ProductForm model)
    {
        try
        {
            SalesLayanEntities3 db = new SalesLayanEntities3();
            Product prod = new Product();

            prod.prod_name = model.Prod_name;
            prod.prod_model = model.Prod_model;
            prod.prod_quantity = model.Prod_quantity;
            prod.prod_description = model.Prod_description;
            prod.prod_unit_cost_price = model.Prod_unit_cost_price;
            prod.cat_id = model.Cat_id;

            db.Products.Add(prod);
            db.SaveChanges();
            int latestProdId = prod.prod_id;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Note that the `visual-studio` tag is intended for questions about the Visual Studio application. Also, if you are using Entity Framework, please add a tag for it.

Comment: Hi i think you have to look at redirectToAction with parameter look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter

Comment: Side note: You should remove your `try`/`catch` block that adds no value (or if you think it adds value, at least make it `throw` rather than `throw ex;`)

Comment: I find a solution by creating a new View inside the controller and redirecting to the page and the insertion is complete. But please is there a way to use "if statement" inside the controller to return the successful message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use TempData. It can be accessed in your view.

**Controller:**

```
TempData["status"] = "Success";
```

**View:**

```
{
    @TempData["status"];
}
```

You could do it like this:

```
public ActionResult SaveRecord(ProductForm model)
{
    try
    {
        SalesLayanEntities3 db = new SalesLayanEntities3();
        Product prod = new Product();

        prod.prod_name = model.Prod_name;
        prod.prod_model = model.Prod_model;
        prod.prod_quantity = model.Prod_quantity;
        prod.prod_description = model.Prod_description;
        prod.prod_unit_cost_price = model.Prod_unit_cost_price;
        prod.cat_id = model.Cat_id;

        db.Products.Add(prod);
        db.SaveChanges();
        int latestProdId = prod.prod_id;
        TempData["status"] = "Success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TempData["status"] = "Error";
        throw ex;
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: But I have to return something since my method is not void

Comment: TempData can be paired with your `return RedirectToAction("Index");`

Answer (score 3):

You are not getting any message because you are redirecting to Index page.

you may want to redirect to success page `RedirectToAction("Success", "Shared")`.

you can use Error page for thrown exceptions which I believe you are already doing that by default.

Comment: Under where can I create a new page to throw the message? Am thinking I can't create a new View for the controller am using.  Am new in asp.net framework. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565098/asp-net-mvc-5-custom-error-page or https://deanhume.com/custom-error-pages-in-mvc/

Comment: And If you feel this answer is useful, please consider to mark it as answer so that community can also benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a parameter to the `redirect` (you will need to change the scope of `latestProdId`):

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new {addedID = latestProdId );
```

and then add an optional parameter to `Index`

```
public ActionResult Index(int latestProdId  = 0)
```

Test `latestProdId` for a non-zero value and then pass that back to the view to display.