# RedirectToAction on NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way of using RedirectToAction where getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error?

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    if(NullReferenceException == TRUE)
    {
    return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
    else
    {
    return View("Details");
    }
}
```

I need only a hint not a working solution. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could use a try-catch ?

Comment: @JensKloster However exception handling mechanism is slightly heavy. So it would be more advisable to check if object is null and redirect if it is. Honestly, _I think_, that production code should not be handling `NullReferenceException` because it should not be thrown at all, unless something bad occurs.

Comment: @Leri I agree - my comment was just a brain dump :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- override `OnException` method inside the controller
- use the `HandleError` attribute (can be configured per exception type)

small example using both:

```
    [HandleError(ExceptionType=typeof(NullReferenceException), View="Error")]
    public string Home(string name)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            return;
        }
        // do something
        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
```

Comment: I don't develop with asp.net mvc, however I do lots of networking stuff with .NET and I bet handling `NullReferenceException` like that will become debugging nightmare one day.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `HandleError` attribute (and functionality) [exists for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183316/asp-net-mvc-handleerror).

```
[HandleError]
public class YourController: Controller
{
    [HandleError] // or here
    public ActionResult YourAction()
    {
        // code
        return View();
    }
}
```